# Are there any international non-governmental data aggregators?

Tags: data-request, data-portal, ngo

We are probably all familiar with [Manyeyes](http://www-958.ibm.com/software/analytics/manyeyes/) and [google public data explorer](http://www.google.com/publicdata/directory) but those are always based on governmental Statistics bureau or OECD data. Are there any projects to aggregate data that is being produced by NGOs, consulting companies & others?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The Data Hub](http://datahub.io/), powered by [CKAN](http://ckan.org/), currently lists more than 6000 datasets, though not all of them are Open Data. These datasets come from all kinds of sources, not just governments and statistics institutes.

There is also the [Linked Data community](http://linkeddata.org/) which collects datasets in the [Linking Open Data Cloud group on the Data Hub](http://datahub.io/group/lodcloud). Most of these datasets are related to research, but there is also geographic data, media-related data, as well as other user-generated data available.

You can also have a look at the related discussion at [A database of open databases?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/266/a-database-of-open-databases).

Answer (score 6):

I would also add that The World Bank has a very active and well run open data program: http://data.worldbank.org/  In addition, organizations such as the African Development Bank http://opendataforafrica.org/ provide regional data.

Answer (score 5):

These might be of interest:

- [CKAN](http://ckan.org/)
- [DataMarket](http://datamarket.com/)
- [Quandl](http://www.quandl.com/)

Also cited in other answers:

- [Africa Open Data](http://africaopendata.org/en/)
- [Open Data LatinoAmerica](http://www.opendatalatinoamerica.org/)

And some traditional official providers:

- [Eurostat](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/eurostat/home/)
- [International Labour Organization](http://www.ilo.org/dyn/lfsurvey/lfsurvey.home) (labour force surveys)
- [International Monetary Fund](http://www.imf.org/external/data.htm) (IMF)
- [OECD](http://www.oecd.org/)
- [United Nations](http://data.un.org/)
- [World Bank](http://data.worldbank.org/)
- [World Health Organization](http://data.euro.who.int/)

Here's [the rest of my list](https://github.com/briatte/srqm/wiki/data) with more links and resources.

Answer (score 4):

There's the [IATI Registry](http://iatiregistry.org/) which aggregates data related to Aid projects published as part of the IATI initiative. This is obviously rather narrow.

There's also http://africaopendata.org/ which aggregates data from government and elsewhere from across Africa. This hub is community run coordinated by the Open Institute in Kenya.

Answer (score 2):

For datasets in latinamerica, a new portal was created a few weeks ago:

http://www.opendatalatinoamerica.org/home/

The idea is to being able to collect datasets from different portals. This is particularly useful during hackathons and other events, when you don't necessarily know where to obtain the data for each country.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there are no big private sector open data aggregators, mainly because the push for openness and transparency in the private sector is not yet an issue. BUT some private or semi-private companies are starting a process of opening up, like italian ENEL (semi-private energy company).