# Where to publish aggregations of government data?

Tags: releasing-data, data-portal

I'm working on a few projects that aggregate data from different government sources (for example tree inventories from different local councils). I publish a map of the data, but it would make sense to publish the aggregation as an open dataset itself. Since the portal that these datasets come from (data.gov.au) doesn't accept data from non-government sources, what would be a good place to publish it to?

The only destination I can think of is [datahub](http://datahub.io), but are there others?

EDIT

Hmm, maybe this is a duplicate of [Are there any international non-governmental data aggregators?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/258/are-there-any-international-non-governmental-data-aggregators)

Comment: [A database of open databases?](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/266/a-database-of-open-databases) might also be helpful.

Comment: I'm closing this as duplicate. If you feel that any aspect of your question has not already been answered by the other questions, please edit your question accordingly and vote to reopen :)